# Displaying a leader board from a text file and calculating points

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

The text file is laid out like this: **first name, last name, wins, losses**

```
dex,kop,5,6

desder,jok,0,11

aslan,vert,11,0

jax,sas,2,9

buy,guy,1,10
```

Code:

```
def points():

    template = "|{0:<30}|{1:<30}|{2:<30}|{3:<30}|{4:<30}"
    lol = template.format("1st name: ","2nd Name: ", "won: ", "lost: ","points: ")

    print(lol)

    with open(r'prac2.txt', 'r') as file:

        for line in file:

            data = line.strip().split(',')

            if int(data[2]) >= 1:

                poin = int(data[2]) * 3

                data.append(poin)

                print(template.format(data[0], data[1], data[2], data[3], data[4]),'\n')

        file.close()

points()
```

The program should only display players that have won at least 1 game and calculate their points, a win is equal to 3 points.

Any suggestions as to how to improve the code any would be great.

Answer (score 3):

Since you are using all the elements of `data`,  You can turn:

```
print(template.format(data[0], data[1], data[2], data[3], data[4]))
```

into this:

```
print(template.format(*data))
```

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3394835/args-and-kwargs) for some details.

Answer (score 3):

A really simple but useful tip; check the name of your vars. Even when you are just doing a simple exercise.

What is `lol` and `poin`, the same with the name of your method, what does `points` mean? Add, remove, update, print points?

Think about someone without time that is looking your code and is trying  to understand what are you doing.

Maybe something like `print_leaderboard` can be easier to read/understand. Same with `lol` versus `leaderboard_header`. Etc..

This is a simple thing, even when you *don't have time*. Because when you don't have time is when all those little things helps!

Answer (score 3):

I would also switch to using [`csv` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) and the [`DictReader`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader) that will help make the code more readable by having *column names assigned to each of the columns*.

I would also improve on variable names - for instance, since each row in the input file represents a player, let's call it a `player`. The third column corresponds to the number of wins - let's call it `wins`. `lol` variable name does not make much sense, I would name it `header` since this is an output "table" header.

**Other notes:**

- you don't need to close the file explicitly - the whole point of using the `with` context manager is to let Python close the file implicitly and safely
- execute the function from under the [`if __name__ == '__main__':`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do) to avoid it being execute on import

---

Here is the code with the above and some other changes applied:

```
import csv


HEADERS = ["first_name", "last_name", "wins", "losses"]
TEMPLATE = "|{first_name:<30}|{last_name:<30}|{wins:<30}|{losses:<30}|{points:<30}"


def report_points(filename):
    """
    Reads the input file with players data. 
    Reports players with at least a single win calculating the total number of points.
    """
    header = TEMPLATE.format(first_name="1st name: ",
                             last_name="2nd Name: ",
                             wins="won: ",
                             losses="lost: ",
                             points="points: ")
    print(header)

    with open(filename, 'r') as file:
        reader = csv.DictReader(file, HEADERS)
        for player in reader:
            wins = int(player["wins"])
            if wins >= 1:
                print(TEMPLATE.format(**player, points=wins * 3), '\n')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    report_points(r'prac2.txt')
```

If you are on Python3.6, I would also look into using [`f-strings`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/) instead of formatting via `.format()`.